# Cookies MVC and Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, cookies

I am having trouble trying to grasp when and how cookies are loaded using codeigniter. Visiting this controller will call an index function, which will then create a cookie dependent on whether it has already been set and load another function to load the view as seen below:

```
 public function index($id){
        $this->load->model('test_model');
        if($this->input->cookie('cookie'.$id) == false || null){
            $this->test_model->setCookie(id);
            $this->testView($id);
        } else {

            // echo $temp;
            $this->testView(id);    
        }
      }
```

Set cookie code:

```
function setCookie($id){
        $cookie = array(
            'name'   => "cookie".$id,
            'value'  => 0,
            'expire' => '86500',
        );
        $this->input->set_cookie($cookie);
    }
```

within my view I have a form and I try to update the contents of the cookie as seen below:

```
public function FormSubmission(){   
        $temp = $this->input->cookie("cookie".$id, TRUE);
        echo $temp;
        $temp2 = $this->test_model->updateCookie();      
        echo $temp2;   
        redirect('temp/index'.$id);
    }
```

the updateCookie() function:

```
function updateCookie(){
        $id = $this->input->post('id');
        $pointer = $this->input->cookie("cookie".$id, TRUE);
        $pointer = $pointer + 1;
        delete_cookie("cookie".$id);
        $cookie = array(
            'name'   => "cookie".$id,
            'value'  => $pointer,
            'expire' => '86500',
        );
        $this->input->set_cookie($cookie);
    }
```

When I echo out the cookie before the update, it reads 0. And after the update it reads 0 I then redirect to the index function. Apologies if this is really simple I am a complete newbie.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cookie information is part of the header which is the first information to be sent from the server to the web browser. So if you **write** the number 123 to a cookie on the first web page -- you can then **read** the number 123 from the cookie on the next web page.

But i would strongly suggest that instead of writing directly to cookies you work with Codeigniter Sessions.  http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html